# Why doesn't $\rm Cu_2O$ fluoresce when illuminated by light with energy greater than its band gap?

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

From my understanding of $\rm Cu_2O$, it is a direct band gap semiconductor. I would expect that the dominant recombination mechanism would be radiative recombination. As its band gap is 2.17eV, I would expect it to fluoresce yellow when illuminated by light that is of higher energy than the band gap. However, I do not observe any fluoresce when Illuminating a copper coin coated in a Cu2O film in different lighting conditions with an RGB LED.  What could be the reason for this? Is radiative recombination not dominant in Cu2O even though it is a direct band gap semiconductor?

Here are my findings:
The first image is under yellow light, the second is under green light and the third is under blue light. For some reason, the camera does not capture the color correctly.
[image: Copper coin coated in Cu2O under different lighting conditions]

Comment: Why do you think this is Cu2O and not CuO? Or that it is pure, much less crystalline?

Comment: CuO is black whilst Cu2O is red. Cu2O film initially forms when heating a copper coin but then is coated with a layer of CuO which flakes off during cooling.

Comment: I believe the structure is too amorphous to display any properties of a crystalline semiconductor.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. The coin also acts as a photovoltaic cell when I shine a light on it.  Therefore it must have built up a depletion region between itself and the copper metal underneath to allow separation of charges. Therefore a band structure should exist.